# Add a property to a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Arrays have a "length" property by default.

Can I add custom properties to them?

Without having to make them objects.

Comment: what do you mean by *"add custom properties without having to make them objects?"* Arrays ARE objects. Just about everything in JS is an object. And what are these properties? Can you explain further?

Comment: They **are** objects. Just a special kind of objects. Like functions for example which are a special kind of objects, too.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730145/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-setting-string-properties-on-arrays) for why you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.prop = 'value';
```

Arrays are *already* objects in JavaScript -- they just have some extra features and special literal syntax.

Comment: will my property be iterated with the rest of the elements? because in console.log I don't see it with opaque text like "length"

Comment: They will be iterated when you use `for(var key in arr)`. But that's something you shouldn't use on arrays anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem for you. A `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` iteration will not include those properties (they do not even add to the length of the array)

Comment: if you use a `for in` loop, the property will be iterated. In a regular `for` loop, it won't be -- since you'd only be accessing each member by its array index. It also won't be iterated by native array ES5 methods like `forEach`.

Comment: The above is all true.  For instance, `stringName.match(/regex/)` returns an array, however the array also has two extra properties attached to it for your reference - "The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the original string that was parsed. In addition, it has an index property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the string."  But, when you iterate over what is returned, or when you `console.log` the result, the result set doesn't contain the extra properties, just the elements of the array itself.

Comment: console.log will show the properties, also if you want to access just the properties. you can do `keys = Object.keys(arr).slice(arr.length);`. Then you can iterate over just the keys using `for in` **NOTE** however that when you assign properties to an array you should avoid using `Numbers` only since they will be interpreted as array indexes. I.E. (`arr['7']` will be confused with `arr[7]` if your object inherits from `Array`)

Answer (score 47):

As other answers state, it's perfectly possible, because arrays in JavaScript are just objects.  However, there is still the a question of whether it's a good idea or not.

That's a "coding style" question, so it's hard to say objectively, but Douglas Crockford doesn't have a problem with it (at least in some cases).  In [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/), he actually uses the example of adding a "total" method to an array.

> Because an array is really an object, we can add methods directly to an individual array:
>
> ```
> // Give the data array a total function
>
> data.total = function () {
>     return this.reduce(add, 0);
> };
>
> total = data.total();    // total is 108
> ```
>
> Since the string `'total'` is not an integer, adding a `total` property to an array does not change its length.

(p62, Crockford's "JavaScript The Good Parts", found on [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=crockford+properties+on+arrays&source=bl&ots=HJljp2s7iE&sig=5aTyh66Vv0HjBW5KNPTc_yHfTNY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aCeXU_OhFdjpoASAroCwBw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=crockford%20properties%20on%20arrays&f=false))

However, it is worth mentioning that these extra properties are not included in JSON serialisation, and would be thrown away if you do anything like `arr = arr.slice(1);`.

Comment: Thanks for including references.

Comment: Also, if the array goes through any of its prototype methods (map, filter, etc.) the property won't be transferred to the new array, since the method was put on an instance of `Array`. Probably expected but maybe not desirable in this case?

Comment: The built in `RegExp.prototype.exec()` returns arrays like this. Try `<someRegExp>.exec(<someString>)` and you get back an array like `[<fullResult>, <subStrResults>, ..., index: <Number>, input: <origStr>]`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Answer (score 9):

If you meant to hide it in an Array, etc. (at least that's what I was looking for):

```
Object.defineProperty( targ, "myVal", { enumerable: false, writable: true } );
```

Then the array doesn't add it to length, so it's a property, not a value I guess you could say.

Then if you want to see the keys in an object for instance, Object.keys won't see it, but *[Reflect.ownKeys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys)* will.

The Reflect version of defineProperty will return success or fail, while Object's returns the object passed.

Remember *[Reflect.preventExtensions()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/preventExtensions)* will (like it says) stop you or others from extending them.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are objects and therefore you can add your own properties to them:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.foo = 'bar';
```

Extending from other answers, here are the following ways of iterating over the array, excluding custom properties.

1. Using a standard *for* loop

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < arr_length; i++)
       console.log(arr[i]);
   ```

   or if not using ES6:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       console.log(arr[i]);
   ```
2. Using the `for ... of` loop (ES6+)

   ```
   for (let el of arr)
       console.log(el)
   ```
3. Using `Array.prototype.forEach` (ES6+)

   ```
   arr.forEach(el => console.log(el));
   ```

   or

   ```
   arr.forEach(function(el) {
       console.log(el);
   });
   ```

Iterating over the array, including all properties (e.g., custom properties, `length`):

```
for (let prop in arr)
    console.log(prop);
```

Or if not using ES6:

```
for (var prop in arr)
    console.log(prop);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can add them to the object by just declaring them and you can also extend Array using Array.prototype

```
var j = new Array();
j.yourprop = "foo";
```

Comment: I prefer `var j = (function(array){return new array();}(window.Array))`

Comment: I prefer `var j = function(array){return new array();}(window.Array)` to give a bit more lifetime to my `()` keys