# I dont know why JavaScript run WITHOUT ERROR about array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let fruit=["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

fruit.price=1000;

console.log(fruit)           // (3) ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
console.log(fruit.price)     // 1000
```

I don't know why `fruit.price=1000;` this code run without error.
Please... explain easy way please
Thank you for reading.
Any help would be more appreciated.

Comment: This is because Javascript is very flexible, and everything in it is an object. JS won't complain if you create a new property and you attach it to an array.

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952126/add-property-to-javascript-array

Comment: Your comment it wrong, logging `fruit` will return `(3) ["apple", "banana", "cherry", price: 1000]`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković FF gives exactly the same result as OP has commented. `price` is there, but outside of the indexed properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add property to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952126/add-property-to-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

Because JS arrays are actually **objects**, and you can do with array everything you can with the object, including adding and removing of properties:

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
a.prop = 'test';
delete a[1];
console.log(a);       // [1, undefined, 3]
console.log(a.prop);  // 'test'
```

Comment: It's notable, that `delete` operator should not be used to delete indexed properties of the array. `delete` operator doesn't remove the slot from the array, and the length of the array remains untouched, which most likely is an unexpected result when "deleting" an index from an array.

Comment: Absolutely! I've edited the answer to underline this. Thank you @Teemu